# NINJAFORM stalling on submit and stuck on processing

Tags: wordpress, ninja-forms

Working on a Ninja-Form form *atm* and the form keeps stalling out after submitting and is getting stuck on processing with the below error in the console.

```
Uncaught TypeError: response.errors is undefined
    submitErrors https://www.dcsdcgrantaid.com/wp-content/plugins/ninja-forms/assets/js/min/front-end.js?ver=3.5.7:2315
    Backbone 4
        p
        f
        c
        trigger
    error https://www.dcsdcgrantaid.com/wp-content/plugins/ninja-forms/assets/js/min/front-end.js?ver=3.5.7:5309
    jQuery 4
```

This is pretty frustrating *atm* as I've set up troubleshooting mode and have only activated the ninja-form related plugins

Comment: I have the same issue. Currious if you resolved it